# how can i refresh fragment content

Tags: java, android

I have **create an app with multiple fragment**

- I change fragment every time that a i click on a button that corespondent to that fragment.
- The problem is i have a function that enable some extra option an all fragment like expert mode when i enable that function my app must go to a specified fragment and all option enable.
- The problem is the app go to that fragment but the option is enable only when click to an other button and click back to that button for that fragment.

How can i fix this problem?

**Code for changing fragment:**

```
public void ChangeFragment(View view) {
    Fragment fragment;

    if (view == findViewById(R.id.button_sp)) {
        fragment = new SpoilerFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment2, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
    if (view == findViewById(R.id.button_bl)) {

        fragment = new BlinkFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment2, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    if (view == findViewById(R.id.button_br)) {
        fragment = new BremslichtFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment2, fragment);
        ft.commit();

    }

    if (view == findViewById(R.id.button_ru)) {
        fragment = new RucklichtFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment2, fragment);
        ft.commit();

    }
    if (view == findViewById(R.id.button_ruc)) {

        fragment = new RuckfahrleuchteFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment2, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    if (view == findViewById(R.id.button_sz)) {
        fragment = new SzenenFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment2, fragment);
        ft.commit();

    }
}
```

**Here is how i refresh or how i go to that fragment after enable expert mode:**

```
   public void refresh() {
    Fragment fragment;
    fragment = new BlinkFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment2, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

The expert mode function only set a flag to true.
here is a part of binkfragment:

> ```
> public class BlinkFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
> private Switch switch_b1, switch_b2;
> private DiscreteSeekBar discrete_bl_g, discrete_bl_h;
>
> @Override
>     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blink, container, false);
>
>     discrete_bl_g = (DiscreteSeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.discrete_bl_g);
>     discrete_bl_h = (DiscreteSeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.discrete_bl_h);
>
>     discrete_bl_g.setEnabled(ledControl.instance.data.expertMode);
>     discrete_bl_h.setEnabled(ledControl.instance.data.expertMode);
> ```

ledControl main class 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/12gbxRStzLDmC2Q0kj7EJsx3fnHpeQ5sQNhWbTKTjxx8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: i am not getting your question.

Comment: The question is how can i relode or refresh the BlinkFragment content?

Comment: from which frgament/actvity Expret mode is enable ??

Comment: expert mode is enable from an activity bar  public class ledControl extends ActionBarActivity this is the main class

Comment: show that "ledControl" code please

Comment: how can i put here the whole class?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/12gbxRStzLDmC2Q0kj7EJsx3fnHpeQ5sQNhWbTKTjxx8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: and here i set the flag true https://docs.google.com/document/d/1spfn69DGJoS8-a09pAwK9Jx-CRa2dmzgaMT5SBAaf3E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: then over there.. just write onRefresh() code.. try it

Comment: i don't understand what you mean with onRefresh(), i create the method and i put what is on refresh to onRefrash but the same problem

Comment: i cant call onResume() because may class is extends with AppCompatActivity